# show registration number on student registration page

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i work on a registration page in php mysql with yii. i created a registration form and create a auto increment registration number from table student_info in column student_id.when we register any student then it auto assign a registration number .but now i use registration form with above code ,which show a text box , but i want display registration number on that place.my code is ...

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="row-left">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($info,'student_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($info,'student_id'); ?>
        <span class="status">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
```

on the place of textfield , what i use , by which it display my auto incement registration  number. i am new please help me ?please anyone

Comment: what is the issue your  facing? and is this form from where you register the students or it is some other form?

Comment: dear sir , i create a registration form .where we use thats code .but it code show on page a text box , but i want display user registration number .what code we use???

Comment: ok but is your registration number already generated for this student_id. Can you post your Controller code?

Comment: here not use any controller ...simple registration form , which use $info (model class for table "student_info")...i want display auto generated registration number on registration page besides textbox.what code we use show auto generated registration number on registration page besides text box.

Comment: ok got it. you have generated registration code in controller. now you can assign it to create.php and then assign it to _form. and last jsut need to echo it inside form. Have you done this? or any issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into your model:

```
public function init() {
    if ($this->isNewRecord) {
        $this->student_id = $this->generate_code();
    }
}
```

$this->generate_code() - this is your function to generate the registration number :)
Then in your view-template use something like this:

```
<? echo $info->student_id; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the user registration number is a very important one and you probably need it all the time, I would recommend to store it at session when the user login. To do so, you only need the following line at your login component:

```
$this->setState('registration_number', $user->student_id);
```

Replace "$user" with the model you use to login.

Then, if you need to display this number just add:

```
echo Yii::app()->user->registration_number
```

in the place you want it to be displayed.